How can i make this horizonatal customized graph in flutter?

I am trying to make this vertical centered graph in flutter using fl_chart. But it has been quite tasking to achieve.
Or is there a library i can use aside from that to achieve this design?
   Expanded(
                                child: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 1.6,
                                  child: BarChart(
                                    BarChartData(
                                      alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
                                      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                        leftTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                                        bottomTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                                        rightTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                                        topTitles: const AxisTitles(),
                                      ),
                                      barTouchData:
                                          BarTouchData(enabled: false),
                                      borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
                                      gridData: const FlGridData(show: false),
                                      barGroups: [
                                        ...generateBarGroupsForWeek(
                                            outerIndex, weekData, ref),
                                      ],
                                      maxY: 24 * 60,
                                      baselineY: 0,
                                      minY: 0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                             
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                orElse: () => SizedBox.shrink(),
              ),
            );

